# angularjs some method for search data result not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Search results are not working while entering the details.

- For Example i have a value "Google Search Result".
- If I search "g", "go", "goo" ... "Google Search" or "Search Result" it is working fine.
- But If I search "Google Result", without entering the middle word, it is not showing anything.

How can I achieve this in angularjs,

```js
return cardDetails.filter(function (card) {
        return (!$scope.search || ($scope.search && $scope.search.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(function(str){
            return card.Tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1;
        })));
 }).length > 0;
```

`$scope.getAllCards.filter` Instead of using **filter method**, how can I use angular **"Array Some method"**

In this code, search is working fine. But the only thing, I need to enter continiously, if I enter first and last, it is not showing anything. Only empty result is coming.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

In your case you need to use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
>   test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value

Here is the working example

```js
const searchValue = "Google Result";
const tags = ["Google", "Google Search Result", "Another Google Result","Result of Google"];
const searchArr = searchValue.split(' ');

const filteredTags = tags.filter(item => {
 // loop searchArr array and test if current item includes all occurrence
 return searchArr.every(el => item.includes(el));
})

console.log(filteredTags);
```

---

For angularjs it will like this

```
$scope.getTags = function () {
    var searchArr = $scope.search.split(' '); 
    return $scope.getAllCards.filter(function(item) {
        return searchArr.every(function(el){
            return item.includes(el);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But we are using Qlik sense mashup. It will not support for ES6. So I need the same format in angularjs. Can you please send me in angularjs

Comment: For angularjs it will like this

$scope.getTags = function () {
  var searchArr = $scope.search.split(' ');
  return $scope.getAllCards.filter(function(item) {
    return searchArr.every(function(el){
      return item.includes(el);

  })
}

Comment: Hi Arman, I have updated my code. I tried but that was not working. So I have posted my new code

Comment: Hi Armen. Your answer is almost correct. But Please look into this code.  return cardDetails.filter(function (card) {
        return (!$scope.search || ($scope.search && card.Tag.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) != -1))
      }).length > 0;

Comment: return cardDetails.filter(function (card) {
        return (!$scope.search || ($scope.search && $scope.search.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(function(str){
            return card.Tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1;
        }))) && card.pillarid != '7' && ($scope.categoryId == card.pillarid || $scope.categoryId == 0);
      }).length > 0;

Comment: Can you please provide your example in Plunker or stackblitz ?

Comment: It is a very big functionality. I cannot add that in plunkr or stackblitz. I have updated my code in my post. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to split the array and search among the it for the search text and return if it exists or not as follows:

```js
const getAllCards = [{
    Tag: 'card1',
    pillarid: '1'
  }, {
    Tag: 'card2',
    pillarid: '7'
  }, {
    Tag: 'Google Search Result',
    pillarid: '0'
  }],
  categoryId = 0;


getTags = function(search) {
  return getAllCards.some(function(a) {
    return a.Tag;
  }) ? getAllCards.filter(function(card) {
    return (!search || (search && search.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, str) {
      return acc && (card.Tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }, true) && card.pillarid != '7' && (categoryId == card.pillarid || categoryId == 0)));
  }) : [];
}

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log(getTags(this.value));
})
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

PS: you don't need a `.map()` chained to `.filter()` as you've put in your example

Comment: Please see my latest updated code. This one is not working for me.

Comment: You aren't using the result of `cardDetails.some(isBiggerThan0);`? I don't understand the point of `return element > 0;`, can you elaborate?

Comment: some method will return true or false. So I don't want to write length > 0 in a filter function. For that I have written some method. And If I use your code also search is not working. The same thing , if I search " Google search" it is working. But If I search "google results", it is not working.

Comment: Sorry result only. Then also it is not working. I didn't include 's'. Its comment mistake

Comment: it may be some issue with your logic (`categoryId`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204720/discussion-between-shrys-and-sathish-kumar).